# Relation betwen dimension of Hilbert space and cardinality of its dense subset

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $H$ is infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Let $A$ be a dense subset of $H$. How to prove that $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathrm{orth.}}\ H \le \mathrm{card}(A)$ ? When we have equality ? I need only hints.

Comment: Well that's not true... An infinite dimensional Hilbert space has uncountable dimension by the Baire Category Theorem but most Hilbert spaces you know of are separable.

Comment: By the dimension of Hilbert space I mean orthogonal dimension.

Comment: Maybe put that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $A$ is dense then $$\bigcup_{a\in A}B(a,\sqrt 2/2)=H.$$
On the other hand, if $(e_\alpha)$ is orthonormal then $$||e_\alpha-e_\beta||=\sqrt 2\quad(\alpha\ne\beta).$$

---

Hint regarding when we have equality: If $(e_\alpha)$ is a complete orthonormal set and $D$ is a countable dense subset of the scalar field then the set of (finite) linear combinations of the $e_\alpha$ with coefficients in $D$ is dense in $H$.